# How to stop process running npm with title on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

In Linux and OSX, I used to setup my process title on `app.js` as:

```
process.title = "xmlImporter";
```

and on `package.json` would define:

```
"stop": "pkill --signal SIGINT xmlImporter"
```

and simply running `npm stop` I could stop the process with given title.

How can I achieve this on Windows system?

Comment: Try `taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq xmlImporter"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command should do the trick

```
taskkill /FI "windowtitle eq xmlImporter"
```

The /FI will allow you to filter, if this does not work try filtering for xmlImporter* the star is a wildcard. Remember that you need to be running with elevated permissions and if the process will still not stop try adding /F to force the operation.

as an aside you have the following filters available to you:

```
Filter Name   Valid Operators           Valid Value(s)
-----------   ---------------           -------------------------
STATUS        eq, ne                    RUNNING |
                                        NOT RESPONDING | UNKNOWN
IMAGENAME     eq, ne                    Image name
PID           eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    PID value
SESSION       eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    Session number.
CPUTIME       eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    CPU time in the format
                                        of hh:mm:ss.
                                        hh - hours,
                                        mm - minutes, ss - seconds
MEMUSAGE      eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    Memory usage in KB
USERNAME      eq, ne                    User name in [domain\]user
                                        format
MODULES       eq, ne                    DLL name
SERVICES      eq, ne                    Service name
WINDOWTITLE   eq, ne                    Window title
```

this information can be found by running `taskkill /?`